# facebook app, post to user and notify him

Tags: facebook, notifications

I've searched for many many hours on this topic through google and also read a lot of questions here, but nothing solved my problem.

I'm making a facebook application, the application has offline_access and publish_stream permissions.
I can successfully post to users' wall.. but the user doesn't get any notification that the app posted to their wall.

I want the user do receive a notification whenever the app on their wall.

also is it possible to make the application post without user's name, (i.e with page name or application name)..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. you will have to use another social channel to generate
   notifications
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#notifications  such
   as send a request.
2. To my knowledge, neither a page or application can post to a users wall.  You can however have one user post to another users wall, or a user to a page/app wall.

Comment: do requests show in notifications or just the counter beside app name? also can a user post to a user who's not a friend?

Comment: From Docs **Requests from your application may trigger a notification to users who will find it relevant.**

Comment: :S i've tried requests but it just increases the counter and doesn't display any notification to the user... Isn't there any way to grab attention of the user?